# wp_redirect and search engine bots

Tags: search, wp-redirect, google-search, robots.txt

I have some pages and categories you have to be looged in to have access to. I am using wp_redirect to send anyone who is not logged in to the front page if they try to open those pages. Is it enough to block any search bots from indexing these pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can always noindex those pages from your robots.txt file.

User-agent: *
Disallow: /all-bots/noindex-this-page.html